# Cabal installation issues on Windows

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am having some issues installing packages on Windows using cabal. The following command:

```
cabal install ghc-mod
```

produces these errors

```
C:\temp> cabal install ghc-mod
Resolving dependencies...
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1
cabal.exe: Error: some packages failed to install:
ghc-mod-4.1.3 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 which failed to install.
haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 failed while unpacking the package. The exception was:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-55548\haskell-src-    exts-1.15.0.1\dist-tmp:
MoveFileEx
"C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-55548\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist-tmp"
"C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-55548\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist":
permission denied (Acesso negado.)
hlint-1.9 depends on haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 which failed to install.
```

I have also tried:

```
cabal install haskell-src-exts
```

However I got the same error.

can someone help me?

**UPDATE**

Output error executing `cabal install haskell-src-exts`:

```
c:\> cabal install haskell-src-exts

Resolving dependencies...
Failed to install haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1 failed while unpacking the package. The exception was:
C:\Users\DIULLE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-35992\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\dist-tmp: 
MoveFileEx
"C:\\Users\\DIULLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-35992\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist-tmp"
"C:\\Users\\DIULLE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1-35992\\haskell-src-exts-1.15.0.1\\dist": 
permission denied (Acesso negado.)
```

Comment: can you provide the error you got from haskell-src-exts? I just tried to install it into a sandbox and that works ok here - or maybe try using a administrator-terminal (start the command-prompt with "running as Administrator") - it seems it could install it but was not able to move some files

Comment: Hi @CarstenKönig thanks for reply. I updated the issue with the `cabal install haskell-src-exts` output. I got this error runnind cmd as administrator.

Comment: Hmm ... you cannot even unpack? can you try to unpack it with `cabal unpack haskell-src-exts`? Maybe try to do it in a sandbox: go to some temp folder (you can just delete it after) - do `cabal sandbox init` and then `cabal install haskell-src-exts` - btw. what version is your cabal-install?

Comment: I get this issue as well, with more than just `haskell-src-exts`, so I know it isn't an issue with the package. I think it started when I update cabal-install to 1.8, which makes me think its a cabal bug. It also may have to do with having more than one version of `ghc` installed and on the PATH. The solution I've found is `cabal get X; cd X-<version>; cabal install`

Comment: Thank you guys. I followed the @Zeta instructions and updated my cabal version for 1.20.0.3. Now all is working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been a [known bug for some time](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1698)<sup>1</sup>, and seems to be fixed [six days ago](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/commit/5c46e7853a09a484698064824b7bf72c5c761993), so update your cabal<sup>2</sup>:

```
> cabal update
> cabal install cabal cabal-install
> cabal install ghc-mod
```

However, if you don't want to jump on the cabal-git-train, you can still unpack, configure and install packages by hand. This will prevent the behaviour, since it is triggered by moving temporary dictionaries and name clashes:

```
> cabal unpack haskell-src-exts
> cd haskell-src-exts*
> cabal configure
> cabal build
> cabal install
```

<sup>1: since the bug has been reported on 22nd Feb, it seems to affect all versions from `>= 1.18.*` to `< 1.20.0.3`.</sup>
<sup>2: make sure that you really run the new version.</sup>